# Скажите, что вы используете для теста приложений, которые используют Firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, avd

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я пишу небольшое приложение в android studio, с использованием Firebase, мне потребовалось протестировать данное приложение, но вот загвоздка: Я использую Genymotion, там нет google play services, либо те, что предлагают туда поставить, выдают различные ошибки. Также, у меня нет возможности подключить реальное устройство к компьютеру. Пробовал использовать avd, но у меня стоит процессор на базе AMD, пришлось скачивать образы, специальные для AMD, в итоге эмуляция просто ужасна. Эмулятор запускается около 25-30 минут, и глючит, хотя у меня 12 гб оперативы и 4 ядра проц. В общем то суть в чем, как вы тестируете приложения Androd, которые используют Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше AVD ничего нет (имхо).

У меня так же проц AMD... Да, до прошлого года с AVD были проблемы, но в прошлом году (или да же чуть раньше (не помню точно) гугл сильно оптимизировал работу AVD и в итоге скорость очень высокая (в некоторых случаях быстрее чем на реальном девайсе).

Собственно что нужно, чтобы всё работало плавно и быстро:

1. Включить виртуализацию в биосе и в винде (Hyper-V). Это главное. Но учтите, что перестанут тогда работать другие эмуляторы (типо Genymotion).
2. Скачивать нужно образцы x86, а не arm.
3. В моём случае, в самом эмуляторе (в настройках уже запущенного эмулятора) пришлось отключить snapshost, иначе после выключение эмулятора он повторно не запускался.
4. В итоге получаем сверх быстрый и удобный эмулятор со всем необходимым функционалом.

*П.С. Данный ответ полезен только тем, у кого **Win8.1+** и процессор **AMD**.*

Comment: Виртуализация в биосе включена, но вот в винде не могу, у меня windows 7, а Hyper-V насколько я понял только с 8.1. А образцы х86 запустятся без HAXM?

Comment: @Skelorc А вот тут я к сожалению не смогу подсказать, т.к. у меня Win10. В гугле можно попробовать поискать инфу по Hyper-V и Win7. HAXM нужен для интелов и устанавливать его на АМД не нужно.

Comment: Гугл мне и сказал, что Win7 - Hyper-V не держит.

Comment: @Skelorc 1. Hyper-V эмулятором qemu не используется. Даже наоборот, на процессорах intel он не дает возможность использовать дополнительное ускорение VT-x в HAXM (хотя и без HAXM должно достаточно шустро работать). 2 Имеет смысл скачивать и то, и другое. 3. Win7 уже все. А 12 Гб памяти - крайне мало. Докупите себе хотя бы до 32Гб + SSD.

Comment: @user7860670 1. Тут (в вопросе и ответе) речь идёт о AMD процессорах, а не интел... 2. 12ГБ конечно маловато, но да же 16Гб хватит вполне на всё. В 32Гб смысла особого нет.

Comment: То есть AVD заработает быстрее, если нарастить оперативы? А на существующем железе, есть ещё какие либо варианты провести проверку Firebase?

Comment: @Skelorc Не обязательно быстрее. Возможно и 8Гб хватит, если у вас будет её хотя бы 2.5гб свободной (но не впритык, примерно столько надо на студию и 1 эмулятор, а на 1 эмулятор нужно примерно 900-1400мб оперативы). Тут имелось ввиду в общем, что 12 Гб сейчас маловато для норм работы с компом.

Comment: У меня почти нет никаких фоновых процессов, кроме дефолтных служб, так что вполне должно хватать, но эмуляция на AVD проходит с зависаниями, хотя тот жe Genymotion работает как часы, даже если я создаю сразу несколько образов.